# Sharepoint, Exchange Web mail(OWA) and asp.net site Single sign on

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, exchange-server, single-sign-on

What is the best way to implement signe sign on for all the services mentioned above. There are different companies accessing these services.

Google searching this topics give so much information.

Answer (score 1):

Using the domain authentication you can use SSO, for the asp.net are you using windows or forms authentication?

If you need to use bother integrated and windows authentication you can easily extened an existing application in SP admin and select a different security zone that uses forms based authentication.

Hopefully this will be enough to get you started.